# System.Threading.Timer async - Merge updates on Timer Thread back to Master Thread

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer

I am quite new to threading so I do apologise if this makes not much sense or I am missing something obvious. Basically I have a list of items `List<Patients>` in memory containing 4 entries.

```
public class PatientAreaController : Controller
{
    private List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>()
    {
        new Patient { ID = 0, FamilyName = "Hill", GivenName = "Chris", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now  },
        new Patient { ID = 1, FamilyName = "Stephens", GivenName = "Sion", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now },
        new Patient { ID = 2, FamilyName = "Murray", GivenName = "Thomas", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now },
        new Patient { ID = 3, FamilyName = "Dupre", GivenName = "Pierre", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now }
    };
```

I then have a `System.Threading.Timer` running on `async` which calls a method that makes changes to the said list. This keeps running in the background forever.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(async (e) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            UpdatePatientsList();
        }, null, 0, 10000);

        return View(patients);
    }
```

The method `UpdatePatientsList()`:

```
    private void UpdatePatientsList()
    {

        switch (addOrRemovePatient)
        {
            case "Add":

                patients.Add(threadPatient);

                break;
            case "Remove":

                Random rnd = new Random();
                int randomId = rnd.Next(3);
                threadPatient = patients.Find(x => x.ID.Equals(randomId));

                patients.Remove(threadPatient);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

            if (addOrRemovePatient == "Remove")
                addOrRemovePatient = "Add";
            else
                addOrRemovePatient = "Remove";

    }
```

The idea being that every 10 seconds this method is called which removes an item from the list then 10 seconds later it adds it back in.

On the clientside I then have a setInterval call back to a server to retrieve this list.

```
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#dvPatientListResults").hide().load('@(Url.Action("GetFullAndPartialViewModel", "PatientArea", null, Request.Url.Scheme))').fadeIn('slow');
    }, 10000);
```

This `setInterval` refreshes a table every 10 seconds with the data in patientsList in the `GetFullAndPartialViewModel` method call:

```
    public ActionResult GetFullAndPartialViewModel()
    {
        return PartialView("PatientList", patients);
    }
```

However, the list retrieved is never showing the updates made by the timer and ALWAYS returns the 4 items. If I step through the code I can see clearly that the timer thread has the list with 3 items but the client call is always returning the full list of 4.

I guess it is because the timer is on a separate async thread and this is not what is being referenced by the ajax call back. My initial thoughts are that maybe I somehow need to merge the timer thread back into the master thread taking the updated list with it - however if this is even a thing I cannot figure out how to do it. Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

I have subsequently advised that SignalR is worth looking at - however I am time limited on this and don't really have time to figure out SignalR (although I may give it a go!)

Comment: I don't have an answer but I feel I need to point you in the right direction. If your server code makes a change to an object in memory, the change is made. There is not a different view of that object on different threads. Perhaps you have multiple copies of the objects (like a copy for each thread)? Or maybe the issue is with the ajax call not working or being cached?

Comment: Thanks for the information Mike. Interesting....! I don't pass an instance of the list anywhere through method parameters or anything so I don't think there is a copy for the thread - so I guess I need to look elsewhere?! Many thanks again, you have put me on a different train of thought now!

Comment: If you post your code, we can tell you what you might be doing wrong. The fact that what's in memory is different from what's being returned means you probably have to distinct objects that you think are not.

Comment: Thanks Andy... I will add some code to the Q now. Hopefully that can help get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I have added some code to the question in hope it will help!

Comment: _"I then have a System.Threading.Timer running on async"_ -- that's just nuts. Your timer handler is invoked every 10 seconds. Then when it's invoked, it _waits another ten seconds_. You are mixing two completely independent strategies, creating complexity and overhead for no benefit. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your main issue is that ASP.NET controllers are transient... meaning they are created new for each request directed at said controller.

A quick fix for your issue is to do this:

```
private static List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>()
{
    new Patient { ID = 0, FamilyName = "Hill", GivenName = "Chris", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now  },
    new Patient { ID = 1, FamilyName = "Stephens", GivenName = "Sion", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now },
    new Patient { ID = 2, FamilyName = "Murray", GivenName = "Thomas", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now },
    new Patient { ID = 3, FamilyName = "Dupre", GivenName = "Pierre", LastSelectedDate = DateTime.Now }
};
```

Make that list `static`, it will then persist for the lifetime of the application no matter how many controllers are created.

What was happening before is it was returning a new list every time you made a request.

A side note: you should [look in to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks) `IHostedService` or `BackgroundService` to do these kinds of things. Doing this inside of a controller isn't very "Controller"-like.

Comment: Ahhh thank you! Yes, that makes sense....! I really need to scrub up on my C# fundamentals! Appreciate you relieving my headache!

Comment: And thanks for the heads up on IHostedService & BackgroundService. I will take a look into these as well!